# How to alter a table based on a boolean value?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to be able to version control my postgresql schema so that if we roll out a new revision, it will just add the new changes for that revision. Example: if the current revision is 1, and I want to add a column to an existing table for revision 2, I'd like to do something similar to this:

```
IF (SELECT get_current_revision()) < 2 THEN
    ALTER TABLE Foo ADD COLUMN bar varchar(32);
END IF;
```

The get_current_revision() function just queries for the current revision (which is set to 1) in the versions table (i.e. the function either returns 0 if the table doesn't exist or the actual current revision).

But when I execute this kind of script, I get an error "syntax error at or near 'if'". So I think that you can't execute an if statement like this in a stand-alone way. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: Why not use something like [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) or [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) instead?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm too cheap to pay for anything ;)

Comment: Both tools are free

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use anonymous code block:

```
DO $$ 
<<first_block>>
DECLARE
BEGIN 
  IF (SELECT get_current_revision()) < 2 THEN
    ALTER TABLE Foo ADD COLUMN bar varchar(32);
  END IF;
END first_block $$;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1f3e59f01bdff90dc872a91657b8ed52)**

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. I'm assuming that this is specific to postgresql?

Comment: @u84six Yes, this syntax is PostgreSQL specific, Oracle has own code blocks and T-SQL allows to run code exactly as you proposed. It depends on RDBMS.